# What is the relation between transresistance and input impedance of a transistor?

Tags: transistors, bjt

What is the relation between transresistance (i.e. inbuilt emitter resistance of a bjt) and \$h_{ie}\$ of a transistor?

Comment: What is your research is showing? Why are you asking? Why do you think there is a relation?

Comment: If there is a relation, that would be explained in text-books about bipolar transistors. So study that. If there is a specific sentence, relation in the book that you do not understand, feel free to quote that here and we'll be happy to elaborate on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple if you know how this "transresistance" is defined - and  how the transresistance is related to the transconductance. Remember the corresponding function (and the very popular graph). Then, the relation to the current gain is obviuous.

Let me add, that I do not like this expression at all ("transresistance"=built-in emitter resistance). The reason is simple: It is NOT a built-in emitter resistance. More than that, it is not a "resistance" at all - but, of course, it has the unit V/A=Ohm.

It relates the voltage between two nodes (B and E) to the current through two other nodes (C and E). So - this relation can be expressed using the small-signal parameter d(Ic)/d(Vbe)=gm (transconductance). And the inverse of gm could be named "transresistance" rm=1/gm. But we should not use the common resistor symbol for 1/gm (because it is not a resistor).

To answwer your question, remember the definition of rbe=hie and the corresponding graph Ib=f(Vbe). Comparing this function with the above mentioned graph which defines the transconductance gm will give you the answer to your question.

Comment: OK - so you realized that the transresistance is 1/gm=rbe/beta=hie/hfe.

Comment: Another misunderstanding about the transistor "resistances"...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean dynamic resistance of emitter junction then the formula is:

[image]

Do not mind other written on the list :D

Answer (score 0):

Transresistance is generally used  as performance coefficient that tells, how an amplifier reflects its input ac current as its output ac voltage.It can be also considered to be a characteristic of a transistor. It can describe the maximum available transresistance of a properly designed single transistor  amplifier circuit at a given frequency.

Answer (score 0):

[Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/glossary/definitions.mvp/term/Transresistance-Amplifier/gpk/316) defines Transresistance-Amplifier as follows:

**Definition**

An amplifier which converts a current to a voltage. It is a familiar component in fiber-communications modules.

The unit for transresistance is the ohm.

**Synonyms**

- ICVS
- Transresistance Amplifier
- Norton amplifier
- TIA
- current controlled voltage source